# LaTeX Error using thmtools: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors, thmtools

Starting to use the `thmtools` package, I encountered a `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` in the following minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[within=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[within=section,sibling=theorem]{corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
This is a corollary.
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

Why is the error showing up and how can I fix the document?

(I already found the answer but thought that this might be a problem also encountered by others - since I did not find anything about this via Google, I'm asking this question and will answer it if noone else does)

Comment: I think you must drop `within=section` in the definition of `corollary` since it is sharing the counter with `theorem` anyways.

Comment: As the two setttings are mutually exclusive thmtools should imho do something like `\@for\tmp@keyname:=sibling,numberlike,sharenumber\do{%
\define@key{thmdef}{\tmp@keyname}{\thmt@trytwice{\thmt@setparent{}\thmt@setsibling{#1}}{}}%
}` (and similar for the other set of keys), and perhaps give some warning. You should inform the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes. At least a more meaningful error message would be beneficial. I'll email him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`within`and `sibling`, both assigns a counter to the theorem, and assigning both to the same theorem serves no purpose, as seen in [Thmtools documentation, page 14](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf)

As made clear in comments, the package author has be notified about suggestion to give a better warning-message than the current one, which simply gives an error to the whole document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[within=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem]{corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
This is a corollary.
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep. However, I think it does not get so clear from the documentation when reading it the first time.

Comment: yeah, reading documentation can be a pain, sometimes. (I haven't really read that much of this one, so I cannot really say anything about the quality of it)